# UISegmentedControl parts collapse to 0 width

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

[image: Bug]

Anyone had a smiliar bug? The control is placed from Interface Builder and not modified in any way by code. It was working fine until some time ago after a random build the bug appeared. Happens in two places in my app while the same exact kind of setup is fine inside another viewcontroller. In all cases the controls are inside a UINavigationItem. Deleting the control and re adding it didn't change anything. This only appreas on an actual device, never in the simulator.

Comment: If it helps, I had this happen with some code.  At home on a prior version of Xcode, all was good.  At work with 3.2.2, they collapsed.  Don't know my installed version at home.

Comment: I take it you didn't manage to solve this?

Comment: Confirmed, building with (not just against) 3.1.3 fixes the bug while it appears consistently with 3.2. Guess I'll have to file a bug report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since none of the solutions proposed actually fixed the issue properly I guess the only solution seems to be to just upgrade to the 4.0 SDK, which seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the explicit component widths or adjusting the control's autoresizing property:

[UISegmentedControl not expanding size for navigation bar/very squished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936450/uisegmentedcontrol-not-expanding-size-for-navigation-bar-very-squished)

Comment: Yes and no. Setting the autoresizing property fixes the bug, but only when the view controller doesn't get pushed onto the screen via a uitabbarcontrollers moreviewcontroller. Ie, if I set the selected index on my main tabbar to 5, it displays fine, but if I navigate there through the more menu, it's no dice.

Comment: Do you have a sample app that demonstrates this behaviour, that you can share?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't at the moment, but I'll try to see if I can replicate this with a new app.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating it programatically? It definitely seems to be a bug, but this approach might negate the bugs.

Declare an IBOutlet for the UINavigationItem:

```
IBOutlet UINavigationItem *navItem;
```

then when it loads do:

```
segCont=[[UISegmented Control alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"item 1", @"item 2", nil]];

segCont.segmentedControlStyle=UISegmentedControlStyleBar;  //Optional, but in a toolbar it looks best

navItem.titleView=segCont;

[segCont autorelease];
```

I have not tested this code, but if it doesn't work please comment... (It may still be under the influence of the bug, however)

Comment: That kind of defeats the purpose of having my view hierarchy loaded from nibs, but I'll give it a try nonetheless.